# awk command within bash loop - recognizing double quote

Tags: bash, awk

I use a simple awk script to sum a value in a split of the fourth column. Works no problems.

```
awk '{split($4,NM,"-");if ($10>1) {TGC+=NM[2]}}END{print TGC}'  somefile.txt
```

When I try to loop it in BASH, it runs, but gives an answer of one.

```
for i in somedir; do echo $i; awk '{split($4,NM,"-");if ($10>1) {TGC+=NM[2]}}END{print TGC}'  $i  ;done
```

The problem is in the quotes within the split - how can I properly qualify it so awk recognizes the split?

Cheers
statler

Comment: Your sample code works as expected for me. Do you have two sample files?

Comment: It works fine for me. There's no reason the quotes should be a problem. Please post some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you intended your for loop to examine the files in somedir, not the directory itself:

```
for i in somedir/*; do 
  echo "$i"
  awk '
    $10 > 1 {split($4, NM, "-"); TGC += NM[2]}
    END {print TGC}
  '  "$i"
done
```

Comment: That wouldn't explain why the result is 1 (instead of an error message).

Comment: That was a typo sorry. Regardless, the srcipt is a little tidier as it only does the split after the condition. Anyways, this works

for i in *; do  echo "$i";  awk '{if ($10>1) {split($4, NM, "-"); TGC += NM[2]}}END {print TGC}'  "$i"; done